# Parse json with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I need to parse a Json array which is too complicated for me. I have been trying during a few days without success. I would really appreciatte if anyboby can help me.
The jon is :

http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/driverStandings.json

And the views that I want to do is something like:

1    Lewis Hamilton Mercedes    384

It is needed to access to different objects, Im getting crazy with that.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Parsing JSON is as simple as `require 'json'; data = JSON.parse(string)`. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, I have tried the solution which is explained in the rails guide.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-from_json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `open-uri` to open and read the remote file, and then parse it with `json`. You'll have to dig deep into the resulting Hash to get to the driver standings:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/driverStandings.json"
data = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
standings = data['MRData']['StandingsTable']['StandingsLists'][0]['DriverStandings']
standings.each do |driver|
  puts [driver['position'], driver['Driver']['givenName'], driver['Driver']['familyName'], driver['Constructors'][0]['name'], driver['points']].join(' ')
end
```

Output:

```
1 Lewis Hamilton Mercedes 384
2 Nico Rosberg Mercedes 317
3 Daniel Ricciardo Red Bull 238
4 Valtteri Bottas Williams 186
5 Sebastian Vettel Red Bull 167
6 Fernando Alonso Ferrari 161
7 Felipe Massa Williams 134
8 Jenson Button McLaren 126
9 Nico Hülkenberg Force India 96
10 Sergio Pérez Force India 59
11 Kevin Magnussen McLaren 55
12 Kimi Räikkönen Ferrari 55
13 Jean-Éric Vergne Toro Rosso 22
14 Romain Grosjean Lotus F1 8
15 Daniil Kvyat Toro Rosso 8
16 Pastor Maldonado Lotus F1 2
17 Jules Bianchi Marussia 2
18 Adrian Sutil Sauber 0
19 Marcus Ericsson Caterham 0
20 Esteban Gutiérrez Sauber 0
21 Max Chilton Marussia 0
22 Kamui Kobayashi Caterham 0
23 Will Stevens Caterham 0
24 André Lotterer Caterham 0
```

Comment: I corrected the variable name.  It should be called `url`.  You might be better off grabbing the info from the JSON periodically and storing it in your database where you can retrieve it for display.

Comment: I have answered you in a different comment, I couldn´t do it here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I m struggling with that since 2 days and I can not see anything. Do you have any idea of how to store it in the database?.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thak you very much. In the time that I was editing my comment you correct the code. What I tried before was trying to store in my database. The code was something like ....
    response = HTTParty.get('http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/driverStandings.json')
    result = JSON.parse(response.body)
    # result = Steam.getAll()

```
@members = Array.new 
result.each do |member|
@new_member = Member.new
@new_member.from_json(member.to_json) 
@members << @new_member
```

Im going to have a look how store it in my database. I guess that the first obvious step have to be create a model with the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is my  code now:

```
def index
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

@member = Member.new 
url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/driverStandings.json"
data = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
standings = data['MRData']['StandingsTable']['StandingsLists'][0]['DriverStandings']
standings.each do |driver|
    @member.position = driver['position']
    @member.givenName = driver['Driver']['givenName']
    @member.familyName = driver['Driver']['familyName']
    @member.constructor = driver['Constructors'][0]['name']
    @member.points = driver['points']
end
    @members = Member.all
  end
end

***It doesn´t store anything and neither show in the view, which it is somehing like: 

<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
     .............
    <td><%= @member.position%>  </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```